# Binding values being ignored, possibly, in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that has a number of methods including one that looks like this:

```
private void TraceEvent(object sender, TraceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
             this._ApiEvents.TraceEvent(eventArgs);
        }
        catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException)
        {
            // The Client has disconnected.  Absorb this exception so that we can finish gracefully.
        }
    }
```

eventArgs has two properties, an integer and a string. Now if the string is short this runs no problem. But if the string is long, e.g. I have one about 30,000 bytes long, then this does not work. I have tried changing the values for the binding programmatically:

```
XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2;

            binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);

            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = 2;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2;
```

Setting everything to 2 in order to break it to make sure I am setting the right values. But it all works fine so it seems these values are being ignored. Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: At about 20000 bytes it does work. What happens is the message simply does not get through to the client.

Comment: When do you execute this configuration? Odds are it's happening way too late.

Comment: There are designated places and ways to change settings, I'm quite sure you don't need reflection.

Comment: I do this first thing when the client form loads. What does "reflection" mean and what are the designated places and ways to change settings?

Comment: `GetType().GetProperty(...).SetValue(...)` is Reflection, you shouldn't need that.

Comment: What should I need then? That works - it sets the values. In any case, why, when the string in eventArgs is longer than 30,000 bytes, does the message not get through? Even if I set all the max values very high? This code runs but the client method TraceEvent does not get called. The message disappears somewhere. There is no exception thrown. It just goes into the ether.